# Connecting to a webservice that requires a username, password and a .cer file using Axis2/C

Tags: c, web-services, apache-axis, axis2c

**--First a little background:--**

I have already managed to connect to a Microsoft web service using C#. To use this web service, I have to supply a username and a password in the C# code. I also have to install a certificate (in .cer format) into the "Root Certificate Authorities" section of the system's certificates.

(By the way, the C# class I use to connect to the service was automatically generated for me with the command line tool "svcutil.exe https://address.of.service")

**--Here is my question:--**

How can I connect to this web service using Axis2/C? The example in the documentation is of a completely different nature -- it asks for a **certificate, key file, and a passphrase**. In my case, it is **username, password, and a .cer file.**

So I'm not sure where to even begin. I don't know where my .cer file, username and password should go exactly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible stay away from Axis2, perhaps use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) instead.
That said, figure out which of the HTTP libraries you are building Axis2 with (I believe it can use a number of different ones depending on which OS you are building etc).
Also you might want to update your  question with the reference to the sample program you are talking about and relevant excerpt from the C# client for reference.